# Grub menuentry: auto find vmlinuz and initrd.img

Tags: grub2

I'd like to know, I configured a usb key to load linux [this way](https://askubuntu.com/a/873445).

It works great, however I need to manually configure the `grub.cfg` file so that it looks like:

```
insmod loopback
insmod iso9660

menuentry 'XUbuntu 16.04 "Xenial Xerus" -- amd64' {
          set isofile="/linux-iso/xubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso"
          search --no-floppy --set -f $isofile
          loopback loop $isofile
          linux  (loop)/casper/vmlinuz.efi locale=fr_FR bootkbd=fr console-setup/layoutcode=fr iso-scan/filename=$isofile boot=casper persistent file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed noprompt ro quiet splash noeject --
          initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}

menuentry 'Debian 9.3.0 amd64 netinst' {
          set isofile="/linux-iso/debian-9.3.0-amd64-netinst.iso"
          search --no-floppy --set -f $isofile
          loopback loop $isofile
      linux (loop)/install.amd/vmlinuz boot=live config findiso=$isofile
      initrd (loop)/install.amd/initrd.gz
}
```

As you can see, most of the code is the same, except for the linux that loads the kernel `linux` and `initrd` : sometimes the files are in `/install.amd`, sometime it's `initrd.gz`, sometimes `initrd.lz`... And I don't even mention the different options for the kernel. Pretty messy.

The thing is that in real life, if I just do a `dd` of the iso on a usbstick, the system can boot on it, without any additional information. So I guess that somehow, there is a way to recover the informations about the kernel to load automatiquely... Would it be possible to implement this into grub so that I could, in the best possible world, put a bunch of `.iso` in my `/linux-iso` folder, and let grub find by itself the kernel to load and the options?

Thank you!

NB: I do *not* want an answer that will tell me to use this or this software to build my usb stick, I want to implement it by myself.

Answer (score 2):

> if I just do a dd of the iso on a usbstick, the system can boot on it,
>   without any additional information.

This is possible only because the ISO image has been prepared with `isohybrid` or equivalent to include not only the CD/DVD-style bootloader, but also the hard-disk style bootloader (or bootloaders: one for traditional BIOS+MBR boot and another for UEFI) for the purpose of `dd`'ing that ISO image onto a USB stick. The configuration for the hard-disk style bootloader(s) will then includs the specific paths and boot options used within that ISO image.

Please see: http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=Isohybrid

You could make a script to locate the common ISOLINUX bootloader configuration file from within each ISO image, read the appropriate `linux` and `initrd` lines from there and then assemble a bootloader configuration file that covers multiple ISOs. But such a script would be much easier to implement to be run in a fully-featured operating system while preparing the multi-ISO USB-stick, rather than within the actual boot process.

Comment: Thank you, it's quite clear. I also saw that if I use memdisk, I can somehow just run the .iso file. But the problem is that memdisk appears not to be supported on UEFI systems. Do you have any idea on how to achieve a similar thing in UEFI systems?

Comment: Memdisk will copy the entire disk image to memory: while a CD image can be handled easily by any reasonably modern system, an image of a DVD (up to 4 GB) might be problematic (4 GB address space limit on 32-bit code). Unfortunately I don't know of any memdisk-like utility for UEFI, sorry.